# WP_User_Query to exclude users with no posts

Tags: wp-user-query

I see that it is possible to sort a user query by the number of posts each user has, but is it possible to exclude users with zero posts from the result?  In the Wp_User_Query class there is a `pre_user_query` action, but query strings are a huge weak point, so I'm not sure what sort of filter action I'd want to use here.

Comment: Would it be any less taxing to simply discard from the results, those users who's `post_count` == 0?

Comment: I was just getting ready to close this as a totally moronic question.  WordPress does this automatically with the `get_posts_by_author_sql` function that generates the SQL for the `get_authors()` query.  Users must have a published or private post to be included in the results. #facepalm

Comment: cool glad you found the answer

Comment: Me too!  Though there is no option to close the question for the reason of stupidity.  Thanks for chiming in though.  I will apply your counsel because I want to save the `get_authors()` result as a transient... then I can simply skip the current author without needing to do a query every time.

Comment: This questions isn't stupid, it got upvotes, please provide your solution as an answer as it can help others.

Comment: @wyck - There really isn't an answer as I think it is default behavior?  Though I've run into problems getting ALL the users of a blog listed by `get_users()`.  I thought I had it, but something is missing.  Will report back.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I was totally turned around by some rogue code I had been working on in my mu-functions/ folder.  I guess I am still stumped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I have come up with 2 solutions.

**Solution 1 - foreach loop and verify each user**

This one is based off of @GhostToast's solution, but with updated WordPress functions

```
//new query with default args
$author_query = new WP_User_Query();

// Get the results
$authors = $author_query->get_results();

if( $authors ) {

    foreach( $authors as $author ) {

     if ( count_user_posts( $author->id ) >= 1 ) {

        echo $author->display_name . '</br>';
    }
}
} else { 
    echo "no users found"; 
}
```

**Solution 2 - fancy pants `pre_user_query` action**

This is what I was thinking of when I posted my question once I found the `pre_user_query` action in the `WP_User_Query` class.  If you pass in `post_count` as your `orderby` parameter then some fancy SQL querying that I never would've figured out on my own happens to join the proper tables together.  So what I did was copy that join statement and add it on to my own.  This would be better if I could check for its presence first before adding it... perhaps I will use a string match in the future.  But for now since I am the one setting up the query I know it isn't there and I just won't worry about it yet.  So the code turned out like so:

```
function authors_with_posts( $query ) {

    if ( isset( $query->query_vars['query_id'] ) && 'authors_with_posts' == $query->query_vars['query_id'] ) {  
        $query->query_from = $query->query_from . ' LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) as post_count
                FROM wp_posts
                WHERE post_type = "post" AND (post_status = "publish" OR post_status = "private")
                GROUP BY post_author
            ) p ON (wp_users.ID = p.post_author)';
        $query->query_where = $query->query_where . ' AND post_count  > 0 ';  
    } 
}
add_action('pre_user_query','authors_with_posts');
```

and then to use it

```
$args = ( array( 'query_id' => 'authors_with_posts' ) );  
$author_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

The idea for a `query_id` parameter is from An Introduction to [WP_User_Class](http://wpsmith.net/2012/wp/an-introduction-to-wp_user_query-class)

Which is also just a very good reference on `WP_User_Query`

Comment: This is lovely. Now all we need is a way to adjust the pagination page count to the new reworked list...

Comment: Good call. Don't know how to do that.

Comment: author->id is now author->ID (small change but id is depreciated)

Answer (score 4):

Since 4.4, you can simply use the `has_published_posts' parameter.

Example:

```
$authors = get_transient('mytheme_all_authors');
if (empty($authors)){

    $user_args = array(
    'role__in'    => array('Author', 'Administrator', 'Contributor'),
    'orderby' => 'post_count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'count_total'  => true,
    'has_published_posts' => array('post'),
    );

    $authors = new WP_User_Query( $user_args );
    set_transient('mytheme_all_authors', $authors, 1 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
}

$total= $authors->get_total();
$authors = $authors->results;
foreach ( $authors as $user) {
    // loop through your users....
```

`has_published_posts`can be either true/false (or null), or an array of post types (like in this example).

Note: I'm using transients here because this specific query can get pretty heavy depending on the system so it makes sense to store it for future uses.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting as answer for closure:

```
   $all_members = get_users();
      foreach($all_members as $member){
        $post_count = count_user_posts($member->ID);
        if(empty($post_count)) {
            $bad_writers[] = $member->ID;
            continue;
        } else {
            // do something;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that the workaround required to get users of all roles?  I'm finding that leaving that argument blank is not returning all the users in multisite.

Comment: `get_users_with_role()` is not a WordPress function or have I been looking at my computer too long?

Comment: It does not exists. Searching 966 files for `"get_users_with_role": 0 matches across 0 files`. Also `get_usernumposts` is depreciated, use `count_user_posts()`

Comment: argh! my apologies. this was a function i wrote for a members based site. you can just use get_users() and pass whatever parameters you want to it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Comment: @GhostToast Please just update your answer.

Comment: @kaiser - thanks for cleaning up my code. I edited it to use the non-deprecated function. helgatheviking will still need to supply whatever arguments she wants to 'get_users()'.